# What do comma separated struct elements mean?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I've got **struct** like that:

```
typedef struct stdHdrStruct {
  int isou,icd,irec_s,oset;
} StdHdr;
```

I do not know how I can use it. I never met something like that. How can I take information from it? For example, I want to get info about `isou`.

Comment: Which part does confuse you ? The `typedef`or the `int isou,icd,irec_s,oset;` ?

Answer (score 4):

The way your struct is defined is equivalent to

```
typedef struct stdHdrStruct {
  int isou;
  int icd;
  int irec_s;
  int oset;
} StdHdr;
```

You access fields, for example, `isou`, absolutely in the same way as *usual*:

```
StdHdr el; 
StdHdr *pEl = malloc( sizeof(*pEl) ); // Pointer to struct

el.isou = 5;
pEl->isou = 7;
```

As you can see, since you used `typedef` keyword, you can use `StdHdr` alias instead of the complete `struct stdHdrStruct` name.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` defines a new *type*, it does not create a variable.

In other words, a statement like

```
 struct stdHdrStruct x;
```

is the same as

```
StdHdr x;
```

Now, you can use `x` the same in both cases. For example, if you want to access `isou`, you can do that like

```
 x.isou = 5;
```

in both the cases.